# Selectize in sidebarSearchFrom in ShinyDashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm building a Shiny Dashboard, and I like the slick look of the sidebarSearchForm.  Is it possible to have a list of possible search terms within this search box, so the user can autocomplete their search terms (i.e. pull from a list of options using selectize.js)?  Or will I have to scrap the sidebarSearchForm and use a traditional selectizeInput box?

Thanks,
Laura

Comment: Have you found a solution? Looking for something similar :)

Comment: No such luck, sorry.

Comment: any luck with anybody? thanks!